# Python: how to get create instance of a class within same class?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a class which has a static method which returns list of its own instances. How can I do this without referring to the class name:

```
 1: class MyCar(object):
 2:  def __init__(self, number):
 3:    self._num = number
 4: 
 5:  @staticmethod
 6:  def get_cars_from(start=0, end=10):
 7:    """ This method get a list of cars from number 1 to 10.
 8:    """
 9:    return_list = []
10:    for i in range(start, end):
11:      instance = MyCar(i)
12:      return_list.append(instance)
13:    return return_list
```

This code works perfectly fine. But I have to reuse this code (copy+paste) in various classes, like **Bus, Ship, Plane, Truck**.

I am looking for a way to reuse above code in all these classes by making a generic way of instantiating instance of current class. Basically replace line **#11** from:

```
  11: instance = MyCar(i)
```

to a more generic state which can be reused in any class. How can I do this ?

Comment: Yes, can't place them in base class, the example is a little different from the real implementation I'm working on. For now assume that I can't put this in base class.

Comment: It looks like you want to create a "Vehicle" class then make your classes Car, Bus, Plane etc inherit from it. There are very good tutorials on Google for inheritance in Python.

Comment: You could create a base class with that static method and then cast the result objects to your specific type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a class method, not a static method. That way, assuming for example that `Bus` inherits `MyCar`, then `Bus.get_cars_from()` will call the inherited `MyCar.get_cars_from`, but the `cls` argument will be set to `Bus`.

```
@classmethod
def get_cars_from(cls, start=0, end=10):
    """ This method get a list of cars from number 1 to 10.
    """
    return_list = []
    for i in range(start, end):
        instance = cls(i)
        return_list.append(instance)
    return return_list
```

Also, a list comprehension makes this a more-efficient one-liner:

```
@classmethod
def get_cars_from(cls, start=0, end=10):
    return [cls(i) for i in range(start, end)]
```

(but use `xrange` instead of `range` in Python 2).